# How do you unlink your MSDN profile from your Microsoft Live ID?

Tags: microsoft-account, msdn

I have an MSDN profile, with points, achievements etc.

How can I unlink this from the currently linked Live ID (abc@outlook.com) and link to my other Live ID (xyz@outlook.com)?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mike Kinsman](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4dcccc13-1d56-4623-b37d-121610073cc2/how-do-i-change-the-account-id-associated-with-my-msdn-subscription?forum=msdnfeedback) Owner Monday, August 29, 2011 8:01 PM:

> I think you're asking how to switch your MSDN Subscription to a
>   different Windows Live ID.  Is this the case?  If so, this is easy to
>   do, you can just take your subscription information (first name, last
>   name, email address on the subscription, and your Subscriber ID).
>
> You also need to create a new Windows Live ID using the email address
>   that you want to use.  You can do this by going to
>   https://account.live.com, and on the left side of the screen following
>   the instructions for signing up.
>
> Once you have the Live ID, and you've copied your subscription
>   information down, follow these steps
>
> 1) visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/add
>
> 2) log in with the new Live ID that you've created
>
> 3) enter your subscription information
>
> 4) accept the agreement and click OK
>
> 5) Click OK at the prompt that tells you the Subscription is already
>   associated to another Live ID
>
> Please note that MSDN Subscriptions cannot be shared with unlicensed
>   users.  MSDN Subscriptions are licensed individually and software
>   provided through MSDN can only be used by people who are licensed MSDN
>   Subscribers.